# AngularJS: Call external functions from directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a custom component that uses external functions defined in the controller, but I'm experiencing different problems.

**Example:**

I want to create a custom input with a external function defined in the controller, like:

```
<custom-input type="text" ext-function="checkLength(this)"></custom-input>
<custom-input type="password" ext-function="checkPasswordIsStrong(this)"></custom-input>
```

The thing is that I've tried different approaches to call this from the directive but with no success at all, like:

***Directive:***

```
 link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    if (typeof(attrs.extFunction) != "undefined") {
       scope.$eval(attrs.extFunction);
    }
 }
```

***Controller***

```
$scope.checkLength = function(element){
   console.log('Checking length from: '+element);
}

$scope.checkPasswordIsStrong = function(element){
   console.log('Checking password from: '+element);
}
```

1. How should I call from inside the directive these dynamic external functions?
2. How could I pass the element to the function from the html? I used "this", but it doesn't work at all.

**EDITED**

I finally figured it out.

Solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/6A9DsCruV7yTQmTRU65j?p=preview

Comment: Here it is: http://plnkr.co/edit/6A9DsCruV7yTQmTRU65j?p=preview

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, you can use the `&` binding, like:

```
scope: {
    'fctn': '&extFunction'
},
```

That way it is part of the directive's scope. See: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks Moritz! I'm now trying to solve the second question: How could I pass the element to the function from the html? Check the example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/6A9DsCruV7yTQmTRU65j?p=preview