# Angular JS - ng-change event is not firing

Tags: angularjs

I used the custom Directive for dropdown and bind the dropwdown using `link()` method but `ng-change` event is not firing.

```
app.directive("reportfId", function(){
return  {
    restrict:'AE',
    template: '<select  id="item" multiple="multiple"  ng-model="item" class="form-control" style="display:inline-block; "  ng-change="binddl()" ></select>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl)
    {
        $.each(scope.freports, function (i, value) {
            element.append(new Option(value.name, value.id, false, false));
        });
         element.multiselect({ multiple: false, minWidth: 158, selectedList: 1, height: 100, noneSelectedText: "Select Report ", header: "Select Report" }).multiselectfilter();

    }
      }
});
```

Comment: Where is defined binddl function ?

Answer (score 0):

If `ng-change="binddl()", binddl()` bind dl() method is defined outside directive then it will not work as you are creating another scope in directive.

```
link: function(**scope**, element, attrs, ctrl)
```

So, due to this `ng-isolate-scope` will be active on the directive template code.. Hence , any outside function , model variable will not work in the directive template code..

Check [AngularJS: Call external functions from directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944084/angularjs-call-external-functions-from-directive)

Comment: but when i bind the dropwdown using ng-option then ng-change    event gets fired.